# Support for beta APIs in msgraph-sdk-java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to access channels API of a team, which is in beta.

```
   API -  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{team-id}/channels
```

and it seems that there is no support for **beta** API's from msgraph-sdk-java.
Can someone confim whether this support is given yet or msgraph-sdk-java just supports **v1.0** API's?

Sample working API for v1.0 is as follows:

```
IGraphServiceClient
  .groups()
  .buildRequest()
  .get()
  .getCurrentPage()
   ...
     // Handle failure case
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

To access the beta endpoint, you can change the URL that the GraphServiceClient object points to:

```
graphClient.setServiceRoot("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/");
```

> More information for your reference: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/wiki/Custom-Requests

Comment: One note, this will allow you to call the `/beta` endpoints but it will still serialize/deserialize everything using the `/v1.0` classes. If you want to use resources/properties that don't exist in v1.0, then you'll need to [generate the SDK code yourself](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/MSGraph-SDK-Code-Generator) using the beta manifests.

Answer (score 3):

update: there is now a [beta SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java) available to query the beta endpoint.

Comment: From the looks of it, it's not possible to use the beta SDK and the v1 SDK in the same app, at the same time? E.g. I'd like to use the beta endpoints in one part of the app, and use the v1 SDK for everything else.

Comment: Not at the moment, but this is something we're considering adding support for. Please open. Please open an issue here to support the idea https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java/issues

Comment: Thanks, I just did that: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java/issues/49