# ms Graph api(beta) Access is denied

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying several ways to use the Microsoft Graph api(beta version) with JAVA.
(I refer this link to connect api "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java")
And I could use all the functions of v1.0, but I couldn't of beta version.

For example, When I request below code, they successfully return the JsonObject.

```
JsonObject response = graphClient
        .customRequest("/me/calendar")
        .buildRequest()
        .get();
```

But when I request below code,

```
JsonObject response = graphClient
        .customRequest("/me/findRoomLists")
        .buildRequest()
        .get();
```

they return below error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error code: ErrorAccessDenied Error message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again. GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta//me/findRoomLists SdkVersion : graph-java/v1.5.0 Authorization : Bearer
```

I don't know which is the problem...

I use the code below to use the beta version.

```
    // Build a Graph client
    graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
        .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
        .logger(logger)
        .buildClient();

    //version change 1.0 -> beta
    graphClient.setServiceRoot("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/");
```

And This is my API permissions in Azure.

```
1. Calendars.ReadWrite
2. Mail.ReadWrite
3. User.ReadBasic.All
4. User.ReadWrite
```

App scope

```
app.scopes=User.ReadWrite,Calendars.ReadWrite,Mail.ReadWrite
```

What should I modify to use the beta version?
I'm sorry if it's a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Microsoft Graph Java SDK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-java-sdk) just contains the models and request builders for accessing the `v1.0` endpoint with the fluent API. (There will be a [java SDK sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#example) for a specific API if it is existing, [otherwise not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findroomlists?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example))

Even if you use `graphClient.setServiceRoot("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/")`, it will still serialize/deserialize everything using the `/v1.0` classes.

If you want to use resources/properties that don't exist in `v1.0`, then you'll need to [generate the SDK code yourself](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/MSGraph-SDK-Code-Generator) using the beta manifests.

For more details, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52416549/9455659), the guy @Marc LaFleur works in the Microsoft Graph product team mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Update: there's now [a beta SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java) that's available to use for the beta endpoints.